# Soporte de la funcion calc de CSS usando alguna libreria de javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive, librería, accesibilidad

Soporte de la funcion calc de CSS usando alguna libreria de javascript  para poder hacer mi sitio responsivo para navegadores antiguo que aun tiene cuota de mercado pero no tienen soporte de la funcion calc de css segun  [calc-caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

un ejemplo de codigo donde el tamanio de la fuente y la caja cambia segun el ancho de pantalla

```css
.padding-responsive {
  padding: calc( (150 * (100vw - 600px) - 30 * (100vw - 1440px)) / (1440 - 600) );
}

.font-size-responsive {
  font-size: calc( (50 * (100vw - 600px) - 24 * (100vw - 1440px)) / (1440 - 600) );
}

.square-responsive {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc( (500 * (100vw - 600px) - 155 * (100vw - 1440px)) / (1440 - 600) );
  height: calc( (500 * (100vw - 600px) - 155 * (100vw - 1440px)) / (1440 - 600) );
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-responsive">
   <p class="font-size-responsive">TAMANIO DE FUENTE Y CAJA RESPONSIVO CON CALC CSS</p>
  <div class="square-responsive"></div>
  
</div>
```

, el codigo tambien se encuentra en https://codepen.io/jasbel/pen/RwrOKMO donde se puede ver mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El metodo de calculo responsivo inspirado se encuentra en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649244/responsive-font-size-in-css

ESTARIA MUY AGRADECIDO SI HAY ALGUNA DE FORMA DE DAR SOPORTE EXTRAYENDO LOS VALORES DE CSS CALC, CALCULARLOS CON JAVASCRIPT Y DEVOLVER EL VALOR, GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO A SU RESPUESTA

!IMPORTANT: LA FUNCION

```
 `calc((maxSize * (100vw - minWidthScreenPX) - minSize * (100vw - maxWidthScreenPX)) / (maxWidthScreen - minWidthScreen));`
```

ES NECESARIO PARA HACER MI SITIO RESPONSIVO

Answer (score 1):

Para compatibilidad puedes usar un *polyfill* para CSS `calc()` usando https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill.

Por otra parte, puedes lograr calcular el mismo calculo usando javascript, pero se torma un poco mas complejo y menos automatico, dentro del evento `window.onresize`:

```
window.addEventListener("resize",function(){
    var items=document.getElementsByClassName("padding-responsive");
    for(var idx in items){
       items[idx].style.padding=( (150 * (window.innerWidth - 600) - 30 * (window.innerWidth - 1440)) / (1440 - 600))+"px";
    }
})
```

Y asi con los otros valores

Finalmente, si lo que deseas es mantener todo el contenido que mantenga una cierta proporcion, puedes basar todas las medidas en vw/vh, y no mezclar con medidas en px, ya que no produciran un resultado siempre proporcional.

```css
.padding-responsive {
  padding: 4vw;
}

.font-size-responsive {
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.square-responsive {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 24vw;
  height: 24vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-responsive">
   <p class="font-size-responsive">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi dolor possimus impedit.</p>
  <div class="square-responsive"></div>
  
</div>
```